# Display name in label (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I try to set player name in my Label "scoreForEachRoundTeams". But when I try do that I get the error message: ***"Value of type '[Player]?' has no member 'name'"***

```
    var finalScoreEachRound : [Player]? // Here I call after my "Player" class
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreForEachRoundTeams: UILabel!
     var competitions : [Comepetitions]?
    let scoreForEachRoundCell = "scoreForEachRoundCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(Player.self)

        scoreForEachRoundTeams.text = finalScoreEachRound.name //Here I try show my Player name 
    }
```

**Here is my Player class**

```
   var name : String?
   var score : Int
   var scoreForEachRound: [Int] = []

   public var description: String { return "\(String(describing: name)) : \(score)" }

   init(name: String?, score: Int) {
       self.name=name
       self.score=score

   }
   static func < (lhs: Player, rhs: Player) -> Bool {
       return lhs.score > rhs.score
   }

   static func == (lhs: Player, rhs: Player) -> Bool {
       return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.score == rhs.score
   }

   func totalScore() -> Int {
       var totalScore = 0
       for score in scoreForEachRound{
           totalScore += score
       }
       return totalScore
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`finalScoreEachRound` is an array not a single property You need

```
scoreForEachRoundTeams.text = finalScoreEachRound?.first?.name ?? "No init"
```

for all

```
scoreForEachRoundTeams.text = finalScoreEachRound!.compactMap { $0.name }.joined(separator:"---")
```

Comment: It worked, But only whit the first name in the array.

Comment: If I do that it prints all names. But I want to prints one name at the time in my label.  sorry for my confusion.

Comment: `scoreForEachRoundTeams` can only hold 1 text at a time but you have an array either set to an item or all as in answer i don't know where you present that vc inside a pager ????

Comment: First I have I VC with tableView of names. And when I press on a name a popup windows opens. and in that Pop up I want to show the name after the cell I pressed.

Comment: implement  table delegate method`didSelectRowAt` and send only 1 item `items[indexPath.row]`

Comment: but I send my information by a button. So is there any reason to have the method "didSelectRowAt" then?